# Impossible to redirect ww.example.com to https://example.com cloudfront application load balancer as origin

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elb

i have built a fault tolerant and high availability Wordpress site with aws  EC2 AutoSCaling Group behind load balancer,

and addedd my application load balancer as origin for cloudfront distribution and addedd a s3 second origin for the second behavior /wp-content/,

so the scatic files inside wp-content are on a bucket s3,

everything is working fine except for the redirect,

the customer want that [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) point to example.com,

now example.com have an A Record in route53 that point direct to something.cloudfront.net,

if i add a CNAMe for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to example.com it give me error,

i tryed to add a s3 bucket as a redirect webserver and said it to redirect to 'example.com' and i created a cloudfront distrbution that point to the s3 redirect but it give me an xml error,

i really dont understand how to achieve this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to provide exact details of your error messages and setup. Its not clear from you question what you've done.

Comment: My setup is easy, 
1my site 'example.com' is server trought cloufornt and set for redirect from http to https.

Comment: My setup is easy, 
1my site 'example.com' it is served through cloudfront and set for redirect from http to https.
2 the origin for the above cloudfront distribution(example.com) is my application load balancer
3 i need to redirect the subdomain 'www' to my root domain 'example.com'
4 i tryed to follow that guide https://blog.chrisdpeters.com/full-domain-redirects-s3-and-cloudfront/ and created an s3 bucket deputed only for redirection
sorry but english is not my native language.

Comment: this is the error if i visit the page This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>1B210EE4A1883A6A</RequestId>
<HostId>
o2GUzrEHnKZHediteditWuJy127+editwQRcpmipir4HdBIejJDUnWWvdGU1gk=
</HostId>
</Error>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>

Comment: So you are getting `Access Denied` only for `www.example.com`, and it works for ` example.com`?

Comment: exmple.com work fine, 
i have the problem ony with the cloudfront distribution that i have created for the redirect www.example.com

Comment: How did you setup your bucket for CF? What is bucket policy?

Comment: my policy is public allow get objetand not used teh autocomplete for the origin but i copy pasted the complete endpoint s3 whit the region,
if i point my record dns to the s3 bucket endpoint  the redirect work but only in http becouse s3 not support https, 
the problem seems to be cloudfront whit s3

Comment: Could use a Lambda@Edge redirect; if the host is www 301 to the root domain.

Comment: I resolved the problem putting s3 full endpoint  also whit the "s3-website" ithe origin field of the cloudfront  distribution that i used only for redirect,
thank you all